# System updates - how to see what is updating

Tags: updates

One thing that puzzle s me as i move from mint is the system updates. In mint you could see what was going to be updated.   The app store does not show what it's updating when it's says there are system updates.  It's not a problem that much i just like to see.  Any way it can be seen?

Comment: if you want to see what packages are available for update prior to updating you can run sudo apt list --upgradeable

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not the answer you‘d like to have, but: in terminal you can always do a `sudo apt upgrade` and you will see the packages which will be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, try run `sudo apt -u upgrade --assume-no` in terminal to see which packages are upgradeable.